# Android-Media Player

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am new to android. I am trying to play a video from sdcard.

this is the sample code I have used:

```
  public class videoa extends Activity {
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      this.setContentView(R.layout.main);

      VideoView videoView = (VideoView)this.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
      MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
      videoView.setMediaController(mc);
      // (1) Web
      //videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(
      //"http://www.bogotobogo.com/Video/sample.3gp"));
      //"http://www.bogotobogo.com/Video/sample.mp4"));
      //"http://www.bogotobogo.com/Video/sample.mov"));

      /* (2) SD card */
      //videoView.setVideoPath("/sdcard/sample.3gp");
      videoView.setVideoPath("/sdcard/robot.avi");
      //videoView.setVideoPath("/sdcard/sample.mov");
      // videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(
        //"file:///sdcard/sample.mov"));

      videoView.requestFocus();
      videoView.start();
  }
}
```

I have launched manually And set the target as `-sdcard C:/android-sdk-windows/tools/sdcard.img`.

When i have launched the emulator it shows `Video Cannot be Displayed`.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You try interchanging the 2 lines

```
 final String MEDIA_PATH = new String("/sdcard/robot.avi");


 VideoView videoView = (VideoView)this.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
 MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);

 videoView.setVideoPath(MEDIA_PATH);

 videoView.setMediaController(mc);

 videoView.requestFocus();
 videoView.start();
```